# Non english charcters support for WP Customer Reviews

Tags: plugins, encoding

I've been looking all over for a fix for WP Customer Reviews.

It is showing question marks on submitted reviews when entering none English characters.

The translation it self is quite trivial, You can just edit the plugin.

But instead of Hebrew characters I see question marks.

Comment: Please always add a link to a plugin when asking a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

This an encoding compatibility problem that occurs when there is a discrepancy between wordpress encoding configuration and the default system or server configuration.

The plugin creates tables like so:

```
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE $this->dbtable (
                          .... Code ....
                          reviewer_name varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
                          .... More table fields Code ..
                          )";
```

The DEFAULT keyword is the culprit here since this is using the system / server default encoding and not the wordpress one .

An Easy way to fix this is to log into phpmyadmin and manually change the encoding from latin (or whatever is your default) to utf8_general_ci

Comment: Please as well show how _the code_ can be fixed.